# Access config during collection phase

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to access the pytest config (specifically the `--collect-only` flag) during the collection phase.

In the docs and in all questions about the pytest config, the answer is always to use the fixtures, e.g. pytestconfig. But I could not get this to work and my research so far indicates that fixtures are only available during the actual test-execution phase and I found no way of accessing e.g. pytestconfig during the collection phase.

Specifically, there is a `@pytest.mark.parametrize` that calls a function and inside this function I would like to access the config.

I have a specific test suite that is very expensive during test collection and I don't want this suite to do the collection in developer IDEs whenever the IDE does `--collect-only` in the background. I would want this test suite to only do the collection during our nightly CI builds when the full test runs or when somebody explicitly runs this test suite. So my goal is basically to skip the collection for this specific test suite when `--collect-only` is given.

Comment: 1. Can't you turn off test collection by the IDE?
2. Did you have a look at pytest_collection_modifyitems: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pytest_collection_modifyitems

Comment: @dosas 1. I do want the IDE to collect tests, the problematic test suite is just one among a hundred or so.

2. The problem with pytest_collection_modifyitems is that it comes too late, because the expensive collection will already have been performed. Is there a similar collection-time hook that I can implement within a specific test_*.py module so that the collection inside this module is aborted (and assuming I have access to the config via the provided session object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint of @dosas to look at [collection hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/reference.html#collection-hooks), I found `pytest_ignore_collect(collection_path, path, config)` which suites my use case relatively well.

The only downside is that (as far as I know) I need to place it in conftest.py to skip the specific `test_*.py` suite that I want to skip, rather than being able to skip "from inside" the test suite. But that is acceptable for me.